# required water mark in live video and other features in live video call using agora

Tags: android, ios, flutter

1. Content sharing/ Slides & PPT sharing/Link sharing.
2. Automatically record live session.
3. Share live session recordings.
4. The teacher can see all the students, but students cannot see each other.
5. Virtual Background.
6. Canvas/ Moodle/ Whiteboard integration/ Real time connotation.

Comment: What exactly is your issue

Comment: Please check this documentation https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/recording_watermark_cpp?platform=Linux